# Calculator in Kotlin with Percentage

Tags: android, kotlin

ok I have created a calculator in Kotlin and I am trying to figure out the percentage side. I know how to do the percentage. I think I messed up in the code. What I am trying to do is when I type example 10 then % the answer should be 1.

Now when I type that same 10 then %, it goes to 0... However if I type 10 then hit equals then hit % it gives me 1.. What am I doing wrong.

```
 private fun onInstantOperationButtonClick(operation: String) {

    var currentValue: String = textViewCurrentNumber.text.toString()
    var thisOperationNumber: Double = formatStringToDouble(currentValue)

    currentValue = "(${formatDoubleToString(thisOperationNumber)})"

    when (operation) {
        PERCENTAGE -> {
            thisOperationNumber = (currentResult * thisOperationNumber) / 100
            currentValue = formatDoubleToString(thisOperationNumber)
        }

        ROOT -> thisOperationNumber = thisOperationNumber.sqrt
        SQUARE -> thisOperationNumber *= thisOperationNumber
        FRACTION -> thisOperationNumber = 1 / thisOperationNumber
    }

    if (isInstantOperationButtonClicked) {
        historyInstantOperationText = "($historyInstantOperationText)"
        historyInstantOperationText = StringBuilder().append(operation).append(historyInstantOperationText).toString()
        textViewHistoryText.text = if (isEqualButtonClicked) historyInstantOperationText else StringBuilder().append(historyText).append(currentOperation).append(historyInstantOperationText).toString()
    } else if (isEqualButtonClicked) {
        historyInstantOperationText = StringBuilder().append(operation).append(currentValue).toString()
        textViewHistoryText.text = historyInstantOperationText
    } else {
        historyInstantOperationText = StringBuilder().append(operation).append(currentValue).toString()
        textViewHistoryText.text = StringBuilder().append(historyText).append(currentOperation).append(historyInstantOperationText).toString()
    }

    textViewCurrentNumber.text = formatDoubleToString(thisOperationNumber)

    if (isEqualButtonClicked) currentResult = thisOperationNumber else currentNumber = thisOperationNumber

    isInstantOperationButtonClicked = true
    isFutureOperationButtonClicked = false
}
```

also the currentResult is the history, and the currentValue is the answer to the equation. My calculator is the a Top equation and bottom answer.

Any help in diagnosing my code would help. Also the Root, Square and Fraction works perfectly.

Comment: *"Now when I type that same 10 then %, it goes to 0... However if I type 10 then hit equals then hit % it gives me 1"* - seems like this is how it's designed? It takes whatever's displayed on the screen (`currentValue`) and applies that as a percentage to whatever the last result was (`currentResult`). If you don't have a result (which I'm guessing means `currentResult` is zero) then there's nothing to get a percentage of. Hitting *equals* puts a value in the result

Comment: @cactustictacs I usually make my calculator in java so Kotlin is still new to me, so i will look at my code again and see where the issue is, however, why is it just percent not working right but square, root and fraction works fine. That is why i was thinking it was just the percentage. I dont have to press equals on those, just percent.

Comment: Because percentage is the only one that references `currentResult`, the others only use `thisOperationNumber` which is derived from `currentValue`, i.e. what's displayed. Because calculating a percentage means you have to apply the value to *another* number, right? *10%* of *something*. The person who wrote it explicitly designed it this way, and you said that was you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @cactustictacs he pointed me in the right direction of my mistake. I had coded the original code in a way it was having to return a value which happened to be `0` so I changed my code to drop the `When()`with the percentage isolated to itself. and then just did the conversion like the Root, Fraction, and Square. Then it worked perfect.

```
private fun onInstantOperationButtonClick(operation: String) {

var currentValue: String = textViewCurrentNumber.text.toString()
var thisOperationNumber: Double = formatStringToDouble(currentValue)

currentValue = "(${formatDoubleToString(thisOperationNumber)})"

when (operation) {
    PERCENTAGE -> thisOperationNumber = currentNumber / 100
    ROOT -> thisOperationNumber = thisOperationNumber.sqrt
    SQUARE -> thisOperationNumber *= thisOperationNumber
    FRACTION -> thisOperationNumber = 1 / thisOperationNumber
}

if (isInstantOperationButtonClicked) {
    historyInstantOperationText = "($historyInstantOperationText)"
    historyInstantOperationText = StringBuilder().append(operation).append(historyInstantOperationText).toString()
    textViewHistoryText.text = if (isEqualButtonClicked) historyInstantOperationText else StringBuilder().append(historyText).append(currentOperation).append(historyInstantOperationText).toString()
} else if (isEqualButtonClicked) {
    historyInstantOperationText = StringBuilder().append(operation).append(currentValue).toString()
    textViewHistoryText.text = historyInstantOperationText
} else {
    historyInstantOperationText = StringBuilder().append(operation).append(currentValue).toString()
    textViewHistoryText.text = StringBuilder().append(historyText).append(currentOperation).append(historyInstantOperationText).toString()
}

textViewCurrentNumber.text = formatDoubleToString(thisOperationNumber)

if (isEqualButtonClicked) currentResult = thisOperationNumber else currentNumber = thisOperationNumber

isInstantOperationButtonClicked = true
isFutureOperationButtonClicked = false
```

}

so my math checks out. There may be a simpler way but this worked for me.